# Did Hanuman exist in Satya Yuga?

Tags: hanuman, immortality

Hanuman Chalisa says

https://www.hindutemplealbany.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Sri_Hanuman_Chalisa_English.pdf

> Charon Yug partap tumhara
> Hai persidh jagat ujiyara

> All through the four ages your magnificent glory is acclaimed far
> and wide. Your fame is Radiantly acclaimed all over the Cosmos.

Comment: Hanuman wasn't just born in this past Treta Yug. He has been and is going to live for many many chatur yugas.

Comment: Hanuman is born 24th Treta Yuga and We're in 28th Mahayuga. So, he is probably appears in 25-28th Satya Yuga.